# How to install openlayers on host (cpanel)

Tags: node.js, npm, cpanel, openlayers

I need help, currently I have developed on my computer with node js and git a gis application using openlayers . Now I try to install it on hosting in cpanel but I can't. Please help me because I've been trying for several days and I can't. I couldn't find a complete tutorial on how to install openlayers. I mention that I am new in this field.

I created an app with nodeJS in Cpanel, after i installed GIT with repository. On openlayers website, i followed the steps with npm create ol-app my-app, cd my-app, npm start. After this all i see when i acces the webpage is tha message from NodeJS "It works! NodeJS 16.17.1".